# Cannot find file in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, file, amazon-web-services, search, lambda

I'm using AWS Chalice to deploy my lamdbda function with.

I want to include a file which is read by the function however, I cannot find this file when the lambda function runs.

It should be in the same directory as the app.py however a simple check using

```
if os.path.isfile('file.json'):
```

does not find it.

Am I missing something obvious about AWS Lambda and how it packages my code?

Comment: Checked /tmp directory?

Comment: @tobin yep - not found there either.

Comment: You can investigate the Lambda environment using https://alestic.com/2014/11/aws-lambda-environment/.

Comment: I believe you should include your file inside `chalicelib` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure Chalice is including it in the deployment file? You need to place it in the `chalicelib` folder in your project. See [the Chalice documentation](http://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/multifile.html) for including extra files in your Lambda deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a lambda function read any files, you need to provide a means by which machine that it's fired up on can read them. This is either by including it in the .zip file or by reading the file remotely, e.g. by a GET request in a RESTful HTTP API, or connecting to an RDS.

Comment: even though its should be deployed as part of the `chalice deploy`? It seems like a lot just to read a local config file!